# vscode allow only wsl terminal in a workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I have these settings in my workspace:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Ubuntu-20.04 (WSL)",
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
            "Ubuntu-20.04 (WSL)": {
                "path": [
                    "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"
                ],
                "args": [],
                      
            }
        },
```

I want to either disable all others or set it wsl as default.
I still have all the rest in my list:
[image]

When I set wsl as default, its working only when I create a new terminal...

How can I remove all the others and stay only with wsl?
Thanks